# How to Match Reference Numbers in a LaTeX Response Letter to the Original Document?

Tags: citing

I'm working on writing a Response Letter using LaTeX and am encountering an issue with reference numbering. In my Response Letter, I need to ensure that the reference numbers correspond exactly to the original document's numbering. For example, a reference that appears as `[1]` in the Response Letter might need to be `[30]` to match the original document.

How can I achieve this alignment in reference numbers between the Response Letter and the original document using LaTeX? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a corresponding minimal working example (MWE) of your current code for us to work on.

Comment: Welcome! Given that the references in the original document are fixed and frozen, I would not complicate my life and type `[30]`...